# Error printout in for/else block triggering incorrectly

Tags: python

```
test_dict = [{"account_number": 12345, "Name" : "Nick", "Last_Name" : "Davis"},
             {"account_number": 76531, "Name" : "Carl", "Last_Name" : "Maison"},
             {"account_number": 75321, "Name" : "Mary", "Last_Name" : "Depp"},
             {"account_number": 12345, "Name" : "Gary", "Last_Name" : "Davis"},
             {"account_number": 45896, "Name" : "Jessica", "Last_Name" : "Johnson"},
             {"account_number": 12345, "Name" : "Kathy", "Last_Name" : "Davis"}
]

acc = input("Insert Account Number: ")

result_list = []

for i in test_dict :
    try:
        if int(acc) == i["account_number"]:
            result_list.append(i)
        elif len(acc) != 5:
            print(f"There are 5 digits in the Account Number, you inserted {len(acc)}. Try again.")
            break
    except:
        print("There are no letters in Account Number. Please Insert 5 digits.")
        break
else:
    print(f"Sorry, Could not find Account Number {acc}. Try again.")
```

I need to find all all first and last names of the specified account number in `test_dict`. All my error checking works except for the last check: when I insert correct the account number it gives me "Sorry, Could not find Account Number {acc}. Try again.", even though `result_list` was populated with information.

**Image:**

[image]

How can I avoid executing the last `print` statement when the account number is valid?

I can't use `break` after the `if` statement because it will append only the first appearance of the account number. I need all of them.

Comment: If you use `else` after `for`, it will execute provided that the loop did not terminate via a `break` statement. In this case, you probably want to replace that `else` with a simple `if` that checks if `result_list` is empty or not. Also, it makes more sense to validate the input outside of the loop rather than doing it inside and `break`ing if the input is invalid.

Comment: I trimmed down your question to focus on the essential piece, the bad "could not find account number" printout. Are you okay with my edit?

Comment: The ```else``` part is associated with the ```for``` statement; this clause only will be executed if all the loops pass and never hit the ```break```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for errors on `acc` *before* you try to find matching values in `test_dict`. Then once you are sure it is valid you can search with it. For example (using a list comprehension to produce `result_list`):

```
acc = input("Insert Account Number: ")
result_list = []
try:
    accnum = int(acc)
    if len(acc) != 5:
        print(f"There are 5 digits in the Account Number, you inserted {len(acc)}. Try again.")
    else:
        result_list = [a for a in test_dict if a["account_number"] == accnum]
        if len(result_list) == 0:
            print(f"Sorry, Could not find Account Number {acc}. Try again.")
except:
    print("There are no letters in Account Number. Please Insert 5 digits.")

print(result_list)
```

Output (for input of `12345`):

```
[
 {'account_number': 12345, 'Name': 'Nick', 'Last_Name': 'Davis'},
 {'account_number': 12345, 'Name': 'Gary', 'Last_Name': 'Davis'},
 {'account_number': 12345, 'Name': 'Kathy', 'Last_Name': 'Davis'}
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It works great, except 1 thing...when I insert any letter (string), it prints ```There are 5 digits in the Account Number, you inserted {len(acc)}. Try again.```. Other then that, all conditions work good.

Comment: @Yara1994 I was doing the tests in the wrong order. I've updated the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `else:` block will only trigger if the loop is exited with a `break` statement. But as you say, you can't use a `break` statement since it'll exit early. So instead, try checking if the result list is empty or not.

```
for i in test_dict :
    ...

if not result_list:
    print(f"Sorry, Could not find Account Number {acc}. Try again.")
```

I would also move the other error checks out of the loop. There's no need to even initiate the loop if the user input is bad. Check it up front and stop early if they typed a bad number. Or ask them again, that's your preference.

```
while True:
    acc = input("Insert Account Number: ")
    if len(acc) != 5:
        print(f"There are 5 digits in the Account Number, you inserted {len(acc)}. Try again.")
        continue
    try:
        acc = int(acc)
        break
    except:
        print("There are no letters in Account Number. Please Insert 5 digits.")
        continue

result_list = []

for i in test_dict :
    if acc == i["account_number"]:
        result_list.append(i)

if not result_list:
    print(f"Sorry, Could not find Account Number {acc}. Try again.")
```

This would then open the door to converting the loop into a list comprehension. Any time you find yourself looping and calling `append()`, you may have yourself a candidate for a list comprehension.

```
while True:
    # read `acc` as above

result_list = [i for i in test_dict if i["account_number"] == acc]

if not result_list:
    print(f"Sorry, Could not find Account Number {acc}. Try again.")
```

Comment: Fixed. I forgot to call `int(acc)`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided examples, I was able to make all conditions work correctly.

**Here is the code:**

```
test_dict = [{"account_number": 12345, "Name" : "Nick", "Last_Name" : "Davis"},
             {"account_number": 76531, "Name" : "Carl", "Last_Name" : "Maison"},
             {"account_number": 75321, "Name" : "Mary", "Last_Name" : "Depp"},
             {"account_number": 12345, "Name" : "Gary", "Last_Name" : "Davis"},
             {"account_number": 45896, "Name" : "Jessica", "Last_Name" : "Johnson"},
             {"account_number": 12345, "Name" : "Kathy", "Last_Name" : "Davis"}
]

acc = input("Insert Account Number: ")

result_list = []

for i in test_dict :
    try:
        if int(acc) == i["account_number"]:
            result_list.append(i)
        elif len(acc) != 5:
            print(f"There are 5 digits in the Account Number, you inserted {len(acc)}. Try again.")
            break
    except:
        print("There are no letters in Account Number. Please Insert 5 digits.")
        break
        
else:
    if len(result_list) == 0:
        print(f"Sorry, Could not find Account Number {acc}. Try again.")
```